# nHibernate update not working for existing entity

Tags: nhibernate, entity

i am trying to update record with nHibernate. I tried several solutions, but none of them work (shows no error, bu data is alsno not updated).
First code:

```
MyRepository rep = new MyRepository(GetCurrentSession());
UserPost post = rep.GetById(id);
post.ValidTo = date;
rep.Update(post);
```

Second code:

```
ISession session = GetCurrentSession();
MyRepository rep = new MyRepository(GetCurrentSession());
UserPost post = rep.GetById(id);
post.ValidTo = date;
rep.Update(post);
session.Update(post);
session.Transaction.Commit();
session = null;
```

Maybe somedy has a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `UserPost` mapped correctly? Are you using `.hbm.xml` files (note the hbm) and the xml file is marked as an embedded resource?

[image]

In my experience if an entity is not mapped NHibernate doesn't complain nor throw an error.

Actually looking at your code in more detail you are not calling `session.Save`

Comment: Thanks man! It was mapped correctly, but your suggestions gave me idea to check on thing. In my mapping file `mutable` was set to `false`

Answer (score 6):

1) You need to **flush** the session if you are not using a transaction`:

```
var post = _session.Load<Post>(id); //assumes this record exists in the db
post.SomeAttribute=somenewvalue;
_session.SaveOrUpdate(post);
_session.Flush;
```

2) I don't see a transaction being started? You need to start a transaction to commit.

```
using(var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction()){
   _session.SaveOrUpdate(post);
   transaction.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using(var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction()){
   _session.SaveOrUpdate(post);
   transaction.commit();
}
```

I had this Batch Update returns rowcount = 0 but expected is 1 exception. But this works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update some persist entity's fields you shouldn't call session.Update() or session.SaveOrUpdate(), you can use session.Flush() or transactions:

```
MyRepository rep = new MyRepository(GetCurrentSession());
UserPost post = rep.GetById(id);
post.ValidTo = date;
rep.Flush(); // session.Flush()

OR

using(var transaction = _session.BeginTransaction()){
   UserPost post = rep.GetById(id);
   post.ValidTo = date;
   transaction.commit();
}
```